# Modifying a .JAR file via a C++ Program?

Tags: java, c++, file, jar

I'm making a program that needs to insert .CLASS or image (.PNG) files into a .JAR file, or read what files are inside. The problem is, I have no idea where to start. I searched "Modifying a JAR file with C++" but nothing relevant came up. I'm assuming a library will need to be added. Any help is greatly appreciated. I'm using Visual C++ with Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition, if that is of any help. This is NOT going to be a console application, it is a form application. Not Win32.

Comment: Is there any reason not to simply use the `jar` utility?

Comment: @Ingo using `jar` would mean an awkward dependency for a GUI app. You'd have to make sure it's installed, give the user instructions if it isn't, make sure it's a compatible version, etc. Easier to just modify the .jar yourself.

Answer (score 4):

A JAR file is a ZIP file. So you just have to open it as an archive, you can do that with Boost.

But if you want to write bytecode in .class files, you'll have to study Java .class format : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'll look into Boost. However, I'm not looking to edit the CLASS files.

Comment: If the answer suits your need, you should consider to accept it to mark your question as "answered".